# Why does Windows 3.1, the MS-DOS prompt and the VM settings say different values for my RAM?

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

[image: Exhibit A]
[image: Exhibit B]
[image: Exhibit C]

I wanted to give my "virtual 486" 8 MB because that's how much RAM I had originally and for the most part of its life. I was then confused to say the least to see these nonsensical numbers which don't add up at all. Why do they not say 8 MB? Why do they differ between each other?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Dos gives the actual memory, windows 3.11 runs on dos, so less memory is available because some ram is reserved for dos. But not 100% sure.

Comment: Might be better asked on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As far as I remember Windows 3.1 never showed the hardware memory size. Therefore I assume it is the maximum virtual memory size shown. This means max usable physical RAM + swap.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same VMware (Workstation) Screen as you (16 MB recommended), DOS from within Windows 3.1 give 14 + MB which makes sense.

Help About in Windows 3.1 does not balance but that is probably a quirk in Windows 3.1

Make sure Config.sys is configured and running. I have HIMEM.SYS in there to use additional memory.  4th screen shot here.

I summarized below and I think your VMware and DOS and my own WMware and DOS are both working properly. Windows 3.1 does not seem to be able to measure very high memory (not used back then).

So your machine:

8 GB set in VMware

6 GB available in DOS

Difference = 2 GB used by VMware Player

Windows 3.1 says 18 GB - bug in Windows 3.1

My machine

16 GB set in VMware

14.3 GB available in DOS

Difference = 1.7 GB used by VMware Workstation.

Windows 3.1 says 46 GB - bug in Windows 3.1

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You've not answered the questions. You've just said, "mine too..."

Comment: My DOS memory screen balances to the VMware setup where it does not for the author so I was trying to illustrate the difference.  I am trying to find a reason but that is hard because my setup is working

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Hopefully, you can provide an answer.

Comment: Make sure in Config.sys that you have HIMEM.SYS configured and running.  I cannot see that in your setup.

Comment: I added Config.sys because I think that may be one thing (at least) that would help DOS (underneath Windows 3.1) use roughly the 16 GB provided.

Comment: @John I don't understand your point at all. And it was 8 MB -- not 16 GB...

Comment: My apologies as I read the recommendation as what you had set. I see at the top 8 GB .  So 8 GB set - 6 GB DOS = 2 GB.  My machine 16 GB set - 14.3 DOS  = 1.7 GB difference. I think that is a workable difference and WIN 3.1 probably has a bug.

Comment: I added a short table for you. I think VMware and DOS ar fine and balance reasonably well. Windows 3.1 probably does not know how to measure that much real memory. I think my post is now reasonably complete.